# HTTP Error 400 bad request python

Tags: python, http, module, request, urllib

```
from urllib.request import *
import urllib

def read_text():
    text = open("/home/pizzapablo666/Desktop/Test")
    contents_of_file = text.read()
    print(contents_of_file)
    text.close()
    check_profanity(contents_of_file)


def check_profanity(text_to_check):
    text_to_check = urllib.parse.quote_plus(text_to_check)
    connection = urlopen(
        "http://www.wdylike.appspot.com/?q=" + text_to_check)
    output = connection.read()
    print(output)
    connection.close()

read_text()
```

THis is updated version
HTTP 400 error bad request, what is the cause ? and how can I fix this error?

Comment: Try printing text_to_check and see if it's what you expect it to be

Comment: No I can't print it , as it give the same error

Comment: Why can't you print it? Add `print(text_to_check)` after your second function definition. The output should be right before your error message

Comment: @downshift the 400 error would be in `urlopen`, not `open`

Comment: @downshift Adding the print statement wouldn't get rid of the error and I suspect OP just saw the same error and overlooked the output of the print

Comment: @user3080953 okay great, thank you for your explanation. you understand the OP's thought process better than I. I will stay out of this conversation.

Comment: it's text file the 'test' 
it is not printing anything after error

Comment: can you the post the content of `text_to_check` variable, which when passed to `urlopen`, you receive HTTP 400 error.

Comment: I believe in everything and I believe nothing. A shit in the Dark.

Comment: Wow that's priceless man..

Comment: It's legendary ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it is because you are not encoding your string before appending it to your url.

For example, in python3 you should do the following to 'text_to_check' before appending it to your url:

```
text_to_check = urllib.parse.quote_plus(text_to_check)
```

Python2 would be something like this (urllib was broken into smaller components in python3):

```
text_to_check = urllib.quote_plus(text_to_check)
```

This means that, when appending a string with whitespace to your url it will appear as something like "Am+I+cursing%3F" instead of "Am I cursing?".

Full check_profanity() example:

```
def check_profanity(text_to_check):
    text_to_check = urllib.parse.quote_plus(text_to_check)
    connection = urlopen(
        "http://www.wdylike.appspot.com/?q=" + text_to_check)
    output = connection.read()
    print(output)
    connection.close()
```

Comment: it says urllib is not defined

Comment: Sorry, forgot to add that you need to add "import urllib" to the top of your file

Comment: it says text_to_check is not defined

Comment: Where are you adding the line? You should be adding it in your definition of check_profanity() before you try calling urlopen(). 

So your text will be encoded right after being passed into the function.

Comment: Can you update your question with your new code? I updated my answer with how the check_profanity() function should look.

Comment: I have copy pastied your updated code and it says text_to_check is not defined

Comment: Can you update your question with your new code? It works fine for me so I can't help without seeing what you have.

Comment: I have copied, pasted and successfully ran your updated code. Are you sure you saved it with these changes before trying to run it again?